# Relating content types to be used in Views filters

Tags: 7, views

I have two content types:

- **Games**, which have a list of *Developers* that worked on it.
- **Developers**, which don't store the games they've worked on.

I need:

- a view that lists *Developers* that you can filter by *Game*, but "Exposed Filters" only let me filter on fields on the *Developer*, so I'm not sure how to do this.
- to be able to add to a list of people that worked on the *Game* when editing/creating, rather than have to update each *Developer*'s list of *Games* they worked on.

How can I make an exposed filter which selects *Developers* where the *Game* has that *Developer*?

Answer (score 3):

[Nikit's response about using Relationships in the view](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/12320/4543) is correct, but it's not clear you've have already set up the correct 'node references' between *Games* and *Developers*.

So, rather than maintain your own lists of *Developers* for a *Game*, you need to use the [References module](http://drupal.org/project/references) to add a field that allows 'connections' between these content types. You might also want the [Corresponding node references module](http://drupal.org/project/cnr) to auto-update the reference field on a *Developer* when you edit a *Game*, and *vice versa*.

From here you can properly relate *Games* and *Developers*, so Views can use these relationships and allow you access the associated *Games* from your Developers view.

Answer (score 2):

You should use Relationships in Views, and attach second content as required.

Comment: I'm not seeing how this would work. Can you be more specific?

Comment: I can point to some videos that describe using relationships: http://vimeo.com/22100751 http://drewish.com/node/127 http://www.drupalove.com/drupal-video/using-drupals-views-relationships