# How to establish a relation among two content types in drupal 7

Tags: entities, nodes

Consider there are two CCK's **Products** and **Reviews**(reviews for a product) how to relate them?

There can be any number of reviews for a product. Hence i may want to **retrieve** all the reviews that belongs to a particular product OR **Create** a Review OR **Delete** OR **Update**.

Is there any module in drupal to accomplish this?

**UPDATE**

I tried this using **Entity Reference** module

First I created a **REVIEWS** CCK with the following fields
**Name**, **Email**, **Review**, **Rating**, **Product**(This is the Entity Reference, So that it helps to determine the Product to which the review is belonged to).

**Products** CCk

Product Name, Product Description, Product Cost

Consider there are 3 products **A**, **B**, **C** and i want to review for Product **A**. I must add all the fields such as Name, email etc and have to select a Product from Drop down

This is Better. But the interesting point is How can i Retrieve all the reviews that belongs to Product **A** ?

If i create a **VIEW** to list all the Products i cannot get It's **reviews**.
Similarly if i create a view to list all Reviews i will get only **product name but not its details**.

Do any one have any Idea how to solve this?

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you need [Entity reference](http://drupal.org/project/entityreference) module:

> Provides a field type that can reference arbitrary entities

Just add product reference to review content type.

Comment: So, the flow must be like this. add content of type REVIEWS and in that select a product(entity reference node) from drop down list(list of products which are already created). Am i right?

Comment: @Ramarajudantuluri sounds right :)

Comment: Hi, Please see the Update. I tried with Entity Reference Module. It is similar to node reference.

Comment: Using relationships in views [was evaluated here](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/12315/relating-content-types-to-be-used-in-views-filters). I'll try to add excerpt of that to my answer. Remind me in a day or two if I didn't.

Answer (score 0):

Entity reference is preferred choice as it's in D8 core and uses entity's architecture. For some reason Entity Reference module has less functionality then [References](https://drupal.org/project/references) module. I needed to filter referenced users by role and this can only be done with References.

Answer (score 0):

In view add a relationship of product entity and select as required, after this add fields of product cck and select use the relation ship dropdown in field settings and in this way you should get all the needed data.